# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ِ (U+0650)

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I used Overleaf for writing Latex document, but after compiling compete I got the following error

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ِ (U+0650)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.278 ِ
        According to these variables, the target force $\bm{f}_{target}(s_q)...
You may provide a definition with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

My document is written in English language and contains mathematical equations. I tried different solutions but the same error appeared to me. Here is all the packages used

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{flushend}
 \usepackage{dsfont}
 \usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
```

Comment: You should really try to produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), otherwise, nobody could help you... 
Just as a blind guess, you managed to put into your file an [Arabic Kasra](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0650) somewhere... if you really need it (for example in a bibliography entry) I think that you need to switch to a full unicode engine like `lualatex` or `xelatex`.

Comment: As mentioned, please provide a full (but minimal) example that gives this error. You say you write in English, but you may by accident have pasted in some arabic character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your log:

```
l.278 ِ
        According to these variables, the target force $\bm{f}_{target}(s_q)...
```

You have an  [Arabic Kasra](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0650) symbol just before the uppercase A in line 278.

[image]

Remove it...